# Angular ES6 - $inject is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I just started to learn Angular ES6 way. I am analyzing this example from github: https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/Angular-ES6-BookShelf/blob/master/app/Controllers/HomeController.js

And I tried by myselfe:

```
class ModalCtrl {
    constructor($scope, $rootScope, app) {
        $rootScope.$on('openModal', (event, data) => {
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.modalClass = 'open';
        });
    }
}

ModalCtrl.$inject(['$scope', '$rootScope', 'app']);

export default ModalCtrl;
```

But I get `app.min.js:60 Uncaught TypeError: ModalCtrl.$inject is not a function`
What I am doing wrong and how to make this proper way?

Comment: But where? Befere constructor it does not make sense for me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far I know you should use the `$inject` this way:

```
ModalCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'app'];
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you, because I was searching everywhere around and I was blind for those parentheses.